# How to determine all possible values of $x$ to find congruency

Tags: discrete-mathematics, congruences

How would I find all the possible integer values of $x$ for the following congruence (or any of this form):

$3131x^{3131} + 2760x^{2761} \equiv 64$ (mod $93$)

Comment: Solve it modulo 3 and modulo 31 independently. Note that 3131 is divisible by 31, so you have only one term mod 31 on the LHS, and 2760 is divisible by 3, so again you have only one term mod 3 on the LHS.

Comment: 3130 is divisible by 3 and 2760 is divisible by 30, so use Fermat's little theorem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a Chinese Remainder Theorem type of idea: Note that for $x$ to be a solution, $93$ must divide the left hand side which means that $3$ and $31$ also divide the left hand side. So, first, let's work $\mod{3}$ (and note that by FLT, $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ for $x\neq0$): $$3131x^{3131} + 2760x^{2761} \equiv 64\equiv x^{1}+0\equiv64\equiv1\implies x\equiv1\pmod{3}$$
Now, look at $\mod{31}$ (now, $x^{\phi(31)}=x^{30}\equiv1\pmod{31}$ for $x\neq0$): $$3131x^{3131} + 2760x^{2761} \equiv 64\equiv 0+1\cdot x^1\equiv 2\implies x\equiv 2\pmod{31}$$
Now, use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to lift up to the solutions $\pmod{3\cdot 31}$